# How to see the underside of a plane in threejs?

Tags: three.js

Using a basic THREE.PlaneGeometry and Orbit and Pan controls.. for some reason when I look at the underside of the plane, the plane vanishes from the scene. Is there some way that I could look at the underside of the PlaneGeometry?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Three.js - Cannot 'See Through' Cube Face](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669803/three-js-cannot-see-through-cube-face)

Comment: I can see how it applies to a cube... but I am asking about the PlaneGeometry.

Comment: did you try it? setting your material to `mymaterial.side = THREE.DoubleSide`? it doesnt have anything to do with geometry.